# Using Raphael how to preserve the aspect ratio of the image

Tags: svg, raphael

I want to  preserve aspect ratio of the image by increasing its width. When creating the image i m just doing

```
paper.image(inputUrl, 100,100,500,600);
```

Instead of setting height 600 for the image, i want the svg to caluclate it based on the aspect ratio of the original image.

I do see the preserveAspectRatio="none", how to change it as per my needs using Raphael.js

```
<image x="5" y="5" width="800" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://whiteboard.veeralab.com:8091/public/images/3a/a82/1dc-740e-4137-9ac0-d3d10b68708a.jpg" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preload the image and calculate necessary dimensions:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {

    // At this point, img.width and img.height
    // contain actual dimensions of the image.
    // Calculate scaled dimensions and add image to Raphael.

    delete img;
};
img.setAttribute('src', inputUrl);
```

Comment: I figured out before the answer